# Deploy rails application with capistrano, no errors but browser doesn't open website

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, capistrano, passenger

I have a rails application that I want to deploy with apache, passenger and capistrano.

The application is in `/var/www/myapp/`.

In my `http.conf` file, I added this block:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName myapp.mydomain.co.uk
  DocumentRoot /var/www/myapp/current/public
  <Directory /var/www/myapp/public>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

My `/etc/hosts` file conatins 4 lines. The first 3 lines were already there and I added the 4th line for my rails application.

```
127.0.0.1               localhost.localdomain localhost
::1             localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6
130.88.111.33           mydomain.ac.uk ngrl
127.0.0.1               myapp.mydomain.co.uk
```

My `deploy.rb` file looks like this:

```
set :user, 'me'
set :domain, 'mydomain.co.uk'
set :application, 'myapp'

set :repository, "me@mydomain.co.uk:git/myapp.git"
set :deploy_to, "/var/www/myapp"
set :normalize_asset_timestamps, false

role :app, domain
role :web, domain
role :db, domain, :primary => true

default_run_options[:pty] = true

set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :scm, 'git'
set :branch, 'master'
set :scm_verbose, true
set :use_sudo, false

namespace :deploy do
  desc "cause Passenger to initiate a restart"
  task :restart do
    run "touch #{File.join(current_path, 'tmp','restart.txt')}"
  end

  desc "reload the database with seed data"
  task :seed do
   run "cd #{current_path}; rake db:seed RAILS_ENV=production"
  end
end

after "deploy:update_code", :bundle_install
desc "install the necessary prereqisites"
task :bundle_install, :roles => :app do
  run "cd #{release_path} && bundle install"
end
```

I ran `cap deploy:setup`, `cap deploy:check` and `cap deploy:migrations`. Everything appears to be fine. Capistrano doesn't spit out any errors. It creates a new release directory, creates the `restart.txt` file. But if I try to open `myapp.mydomain.co.uk` in the Browser, it can't open it. The logfile is empty.

Any ideas what might be going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the Passenger-specific configuration to Apache conf ? I fail to see it in your example!

Comment: Yes, I added the 3 lines that passenger asked me to put into httpd.conf: LoadModule passenger_module /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.11/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.11
PassengerRuby /usr/local/bin/ruby

Comment: Have you checked all logs (both apache's error.log and your Rails app's in APP/shared/log/production.log) ? Can you start the app in production from the command line?

Comment: The apps production.log is empty and apache's error.log doesn't contain anything related to the rails app or virtual host. How do I start the app in production from the command line? I deployed it with WebRick in development mode before and it was working absolutely fine.

Comment: `rails s -e production` and make sure you migrate production first. Just to make sure is that log's path `/var/www/myapp/current/log/production.log` or `/var/www/myapp/shared/log/production.log` ?

Comment: But `rails s -e production` runs WebRick. I want to deploy it on Apache, not WebRick. The logfiles are under current, but they are empty.

Answer (score 0):

Did you see if current folder is created in the /var/www/myapp folder?
Usually you have to run "cap deploy" after cap deploy:migrations

Comment: Yes, it's created and I did run cap deploy. I'm pretty sure that everything is properly set on the capistrano site. I suspect that I did something wrong with the apache configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your vhost definition. In the Directory block you are missing the /current folder. The DocumentRoot is okay.

```
....
DocumentRoot /var/www/myapp/current/public
<Directory /var/www/myapp/public>
...
```

vs

```
...
DocumentRoot /var/www/myapp/current/public
<Directory /var/www/myapp/current/public>
...
```

Does this fix your problem?